# How to convert WGS84 coordinate to UTM?

Tags: javascript, map-projections, utm, wgs84, proj4js

How can I convert geo coordinates from WGS 84 to UTM using JavaScript?

I tried using proj4js, but it yields these coordinates: `32U 5114272 1633427`, whereas [external sources](https://geohack.toolforge.org/geohack.php?params=48.171974_N_11.532256_E_region:DE-BY_type:landmark&pagename=Stadtwerke_M%C3%BCnchen&language=de) tell us, that `32U 688260 5338516` would be correct.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961581/coordinates-convert-from-wgs84-to-a-specific-utm-region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably got confused with Lon/Lat. If you set **Lon** (x) to `11...` and **Lat** (y) to `48...`, then everything works as expected.

```js
proj4.defs("EPSG:32632","+proj=utm +zone=32"); // https://epsg.io/32632

const sourceProj = new proj4.Proj('WGS84');
const destProj = new proj4.Proj('EPSG:32632');

function calc() {
  const x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('srcX').value)
  const y = parseFloat(document.getElementById('srcY').value)

  const p = new proj4.Point(x, y);
  const r = proj4.transform(sourceProj, destProj, p);

  document.getElementById('tgtX').value = r.x
  document.getElementById('tgtY').value = r.y
  console.log(x, y, p, r, r.x, r.y)
}

calc()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.2/proj4.js"></script>
<pre>

From WGS84
Lon: <input type="number" id="srcX" value="11.532256" onchange="calc()"/>°
Lat: <input type="number" id="srcY" value="48.171974" onchange="calc()"/>°

To UTM 32U
X  : <input type="number" id="tgtX" value="" readonly/>
Y  : <input type="number" id="tgtY" value="" readonly/>

</pre>
```